Win7 legacy software MSR migration to GPT
Ryzen 7 on asus roc strix 550-F with 2 x 4gb SSD gpt 7400mb m2 drives boots Win10.  Legacy system no post. All software on MBR 2gb hdd.  How do I migrate without reinstalling 20 year collection of software including Adobe Master Collection 5.5 for which Adobe refuses licensing migration. Bios locks when I try to plug in MBR drive.  Thanks

You don't, it's as simple as that. Even if you could, most if not all of the old software wouldn't run in current OS.

There is no safe way to convert MBR to GPT as long as you are running Windows 7. By MSR I assume you mean MBR.


Create a Windows 7 virtual machine, e.g., VirtualBox or an alternative.
Migrate what software you can.
For software with subscriptions or obnoxious licensing requirements, consider other choices.

If you don't want to purchase new software (currently, Adobe Creative Cloud Entire Collection is ~US$90/month at Amazon), look for open-source equivalents, such as free, open-source, GIMP or alternatives.
